# Generating a graphic for publication: How to change color and border weight of shapefiles in ArcGIS Pro 2.4.0?

Tags: shapefile, arcgis-pro, color, borders

I am trying to generating a graphic for publication. I am using ArcGIS Pro 2.4.0, and I am trying to draw a border around experiment plots using a rectangular shape file. As can be seen in the below image, I have drawn a black rectangle (arbitrarily) as an example.

[image]

I like this symbol format, but I'm trying to change the border to white, as well as change the border weight to a smaller size. How do I do this? I have tried clicking on "symbology" and "properties," but I don't see a way to change the border color/weight. I also looked on the "Appearance", "Labeling", and "Data" tabs at the top, but still didn't get anything.

Edit: Would it be a better idea to add a shape, instead of a shape file for this purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to generate a new map layout before adding shapes for illustrative purposes. This will allow for shapes to be drawn and modified.